# Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2022

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **September 19th, 2022** to bring in 1 more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on September 19, users can [nominate themselves](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On September 26, if there are 2 or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period, there is 1 candidate, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year).)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on October 4, 2022 (or October 11, 2022, if we need to extend the nomination period).

  - **Update: The election, which was scheduled to end on October 11, has been extended until October 18, 2022.**

If you have any questions about the process, please post them in an answer here.

Comment: Too bad I can't join since I am not 18 years old yet... I would really like to have joined

Comment: Since we found (and fixed) a bug preventing some votes from being saved, I made a new post here as a reminder: [The moderator election has been extended until October 18, 2022 – please check your ballots to ensure your selections have been saved!](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/763/20202)