# The moderator election has been extended until October 18, 2022 – please check your ballots to ensure your selections have been saved!

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

As some of you may know, we recently [identified a bug affecting moderator elections](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/759/20202) – and [fixed it](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/762/20202). This bug was preventing some users' election ballots (i.e. selections) from being saved in a very rare edge case:

> The bug only happens in a very specific set of super unlikely circumstances: we were mistakenly checking the Id of a nomination against the Id of a user (instead of comparing UserId to UserId), and when those overlapped, that user's nomination was incorrectly marked as withdrawn. It was never caught because this situation is remarkably unlikely so we weren't able to find any issues while testing.

Because ballots were not being saved, the election also had very low turnout; the system indicated that only ~17 users had voted by the time the election was originally supposed to conclude (October 11, 2022 @ 20:00 UTC). As a result, we decided to extend the end of the voting phase of the election by 1 week.

This bug has now been fixed. Going forward, all ballots should be getting saved properly, as long as you rank the candidates by dragging them into the numbered rankings at the top of the ballot on the election page (i.e. the "1. (Drag next selection here)" area). However, that doesn't restore the previously attempted selections that weren't getting saved, so it's important that you check your ballots to make your votes will be counted.

**Please go to [the election page](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election) by October 18, 2022 (20:00 UTC) to ensure that you've ranked the candidates you want to vote for, and that your selections have been saved.** If your ballot wasn't saved, please rank your desired candidates again. (You can change your selections at any time before the election ends.)

After you've ranked one or more candidates, your selections should be automatically saved. If they have been successfully saved, then you should see your current ranking of the candidates (in the numbered list under "Your ballot") when you reload or return to this page.

Please check that your ballot has been saved. We want to make sure everyone's vote is counted!

Comment: Thanks V2Blast for getting the bug fixed and making sure the community has a chance to vote now that it is resolved.

Comment: "very unlikely" I had this all the time last week :)

Comment: @Irsu85: It was an unlikely circumstance in general; it just happened to be very relevant this election (due to the user/post IDs involved).

Comment: Ah I see why. One of the canadates (Undo) is both user id 1 and canidate id 1